# Question on the Subject Complex analysis (Maybe Hurwitz's theorem?)

Tags: complex-analysis

This is the question:

[image]

I solved section a, but didn't managed to solve section b.
I tried to use section a, in order to define for every $k$, function series that goes to $H_k$ (with the $k$ derivatives of the series in section a). Then I tried to claim that this function series have only real zeros in order to use Hurwitz's theorem. But I didn't managed to prove that that this function series have only real zeros.

Thank you very much!
Peleg

Comment: from what book is this exercise? Just to see the previous theorems.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! unfortunately I don't know from what book this exercise is taking. This question gave to me by my professor for practice in the subject of argument principle, and Rouché's and Hurwitz's theorem.

Comment: Using the Cauchy formula and then the "strong" DCT (about the $L^1$ norm rather than merely convergence of integrals), it's enough to show for a) that the sequence is uniformly bounded on each compact and converges pointwise. Both are easy to do. For b), I think you can use Rolle and induction, showing that $H_k(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ with real coefficients.

Comment: Thank you very much! By rolle, do you reffer to the theorem for real functions that gives me point in which the derivative is zero? How this is helps me to prove that Hk is polynomial with real coefficients? also, even if i prove this, I think that it still may have complex zero. What am I missing?